# Permission denied: AWS Amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, terminal, aws-amplify

I have installed the aws amplify package successful with `npm i -g @aws-amplify/cli`.

When I run `amplify configure` I get the following error:

`zsh: permission denied: amplify`

I have tried this in different directories but I get the same error each time. I am using npm v18.9.3 and node 18.13.0. Both of these should be sufficient to run AWS amplify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd check if you have all the permissions and that you've installed `amplify` as local user.

Run this:

```bash
npm doctor
```

Check if you see this, for example:

```bash
global bin folder in PATH           ok      /usr/local/bin
Perms check on cached files         ok       
Perms check on local node_modules   ok       
Perms check on global node_modules  ok       
Perms check on local bin folder     ok
```

Then, see your installed packages with:

```bash
npm list -g --depth=0
```

Is `amplify` there?

Also, how did you get the node installed? The error might to do with `amplify` not being installed in the `usr/local` folder.

Try these commands and double check your installation:

```bash
npm config get prefix
```

This should give you: `/usr/local`

```bash
which amplify
```

Should print: `/usr/local/bin/amplify`.

If you're trying to install the package globally, check this [npm doc](https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally) on how to resolve `access denied` issues.

Also, try reinstalling the `amplify cli` with this:

```bash
sudo npm install -g @aws-amplify/cli --unsafe-perm=true
amplify configure
```

Comment: I followed your steps and was able to run an amplify command for the first time. 

When I run `amplify configure`, I get a EACCES error but it redirects me to the AWS site (I have also followed all the steps on the npm doc which has lead to no change). So I'm not sure if it installed correctly.

Comment: Check the page about EACCES, but, alternatively you can assume ownership over the folders created in your home directory but owned by `root`. Try this: `chown -R ~/.amplify`. And then rerun `amplify configure`.

Comment: I've checked the npm doc on EACCES and followed the steps. I was able to run npm install from the command line but I sill cannot run amplify configure. I also tried `chown -R ~/.amplify` to no luck. Any other workarounds?

Comment: Have you tried this already? `sudo npm install -g @aws-amplify/cli --unsafe-perm=true`

Comment: Yes, that's how I installed aws amplify (since `npm install -g @aws-amplify/cli` results in a error)

Comment: Are you the admin of the computer you're installing npm at? How and where is node installed?

Comment: And how do you install software on your mac? Manually or with `brew`?

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue. The `~/.amplify/bin/amplify` exists, with right permissions but not on `PATH` for unknown reason. And if I ran `% npm uninstall -g @aws-amplify/cli` it didn't remove amplify from User root.

Then I've decided to run `% ~/.amplify/bin/amplify uninstall`, it [uninstalls amplify cli,](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/commands/uninstall/) and reinstall it from  npm `% npm install -g @aws-amplify/cli`. It definitely fixed the issue.